# How to edit previously applied migration without adding another migration in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an applied migration using "haward" db schema.

```
public partial class CreateCourseCategoryTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "haward.CourseCategories",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        Code = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("haward.CourseCategories");
        }
    }
```

with this mapping

```
public class CourseCategoryMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<CourseCategory>
    {
        public CourseCategoryMapping()
        {
            ToTable("CourseCategories", "haward");
        }
    }
```

now I want to change the schema from "haward" to "tr"
I dont want to add migration with this one so I thought of just editing directly the source code of the Migration and Mapping.

```
public partial class CreateCourseCategoryTable : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {
                CreateTable(
                    "tr.CourseCategories",
                    c => new
                        {
                            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            Name = c.String(),
                            Code = c.String(),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            }

            public override void Down()
            {
                DropTable("tr.CourseCategories");
            }
        }


    public class CourseCategoryMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<CourseCategory>
        {
            public CourseCategoryMapping()
            {
                ToTable("CourseCategories", "tr");
            }
        }
```

then recreate empty database and issued the command update-database
but its telling that I still have pending changes.

so what I did was issued the add-migration command to check which changes are those. and it seems like it still detects my edits(from "haward" to "tr" schema) even without the migrations table.

where do the model changes being saved? and how to edit directly the source code and reapply the migration? I know its not advisable because thats what migration is for. but I dont want to get my history dirty with just those changes specially if I am only at early development stage.

Answer (score 27):

**TL;DR:** This is very complicated - it's a lot easier just to add a new migration later to correct the problem.

An Entity Framework migration consists of two parts - the code, and a hash of the model.  The hash of the model is used to determine whether the model has changed, and hence whether any new migrations are required.

If you change the model, you change the hash.  This hash is stored in the MigrationName.designer.cs file.  You cannot just edit the model and change the migration.cs code, as the model no longer matches the model hash.  You also need to regenerate the hash for the model.

The only way to do this is to roll your database back, and update the hash.

Consider you have 3 migrations applied:

- Migration1
- Migration2
- Migration3

If you want to apply a change from Migration2 onwards...

- Roll back to Migration1: `Update-Database -TargetMigration Migration1 -Force` (NB - This may cause data loss, so work on a development copy of your database)
- Make your model code match what you wanted for Migration 2, and update the code for Migration 2 by hand
- Regenerate the designer file for Migration2: `Add-Migration xxxxxxxxxxx_Migration2` (use the full name of the migration including the date).  This will only update the designer.cs file
- Apply Migration2: `Update-Database -TargetMigration Migration2`
- Reapply any model changes to your code for Migration3
- Regenerate the designer file for Migration3: `Add-Migration xxxxxxxxxxx_Migration3`
- Update the database to latest: `Update-Database`

Comment: In order to Rollback to Migration1 you should do ```Update-Database -TargetMigration Migration1 -Force``` I can't make the edit because is only one character.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this helps anyone else, but I was able to edit and re-apply a migration by performing the following:

1. Delete the record of the migration from the _MigrationHistory table.  Find the one with a "migrationId" that matches your migration class file name and delete it.
2. Manually undo all of the previous migration's changes (which would have been everything in the Down() section of your migration class file before you added the new stuff).
3. Update-Database (or whatever you do to apply your migrations.  I have auto-migration turned on so I just run my app).

My migration was pretty simple so I'm not sure if this will work for everyone.

Enjoy!

Comment: I think your answer is the best one, except that changing migration outside of dev environment or after the migration was already committed is a very bad idea. The correct way is to introduce a new migration that applies the needed changes. Even if it was just a typo.

Comment: Yes it does what's required. One more thing that needs to be done along with above mentioned steps is to remove data from "ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot" class. I had data in it but on creating new migration data was not showing up, and i had removed relevant data from database as well, so i had to remove data so that it can be added again. That was just my case but it can help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, this will be the simple one to followed.
Remove the migration from the code base
and Add the same migration after updating the model class.

Then to update-database command.
This will work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way of doing this but, if you're using a version control system (Git, Subversion, etc.), there's another option. It's a bit more toilsome but was the only one that worked for me.

Considering you have the following migrations:

- Migration1
- Migration2
- Migration3

Assuming you want to change **Migration2**, you could follow the steps below:

1. Create a patch with the changes you want to be applied to **Migration2**
2. Check out the commit immediately before the migration you want to avoid (in this case, Migration3 - It will look like you have just created Migration2)
3. Update the DB to **Migration1** - `Update-Database -TargetMigration Migration1 -Force`
4. Apply the patch you created on step 1
5. Recreate **Migration2** - `Add-Migration Migration2` (it will now contain exactly the changes you want)
6. Copy the migration files created to a different directory
7. Revert all the uncommitted changes
8. Check out the HEAD commit again
9. Delete the files for **Migration2** and **Migration3**
10. Copy the files from step 6 back to their original directory
11. Update the database - `Update-Database`
12. Recreate **Migration3** - `Add-Migration Migration3`
13. Update the database again - `Update-Database`